# Angular.js two-way binding do not work when update the $scope in the controller of custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, watch

I met this when I was writing a group of directives which can contact with each other.

Here is the CodePen url: http://codepen.io/jennieji/pen/mDGuw

Here is the JS code:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('testDirective', function() {
  return {
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.now = 0;

      this.update = function() {
        $scope.now++;
      };
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.$watch(function(){
        return scope.now;
      }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
        element.append('<p>[LOG] $watch now:' + newVal + '</p>');
      }, true);
      scope.$watch('now', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        element.append('<p>[LOG] $watch now:' + newVal + '</p>');
      });
    }
  };
})
.directive('testUpdate', function() {
  return {
    require: '^testDirective',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      element.on('click', function(){
        ctrl.update();
        element.after('<p>[LOG] click now:' + scope.now + '</p>');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div test-directive>
    <p>{{ now }}</p>
    <button test-update>Update now</button>
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are listening for the DOM click event:

`element.on('click', function(){`

Your scope changes will not take effect unless you `$apply` them:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      element.on('click', function(){

        scope.$apply(function() {
          ctrl.update();
        });
        ctrl.update();
        element.after('<p>[LOG] click now:' + scope.now + '</p>');

      });
    }
```

`$apply` kicks off an Angular `$digest` loop and does the dirty check for the two-way bind.

Comment: The two-way binding works! But the $watch still not working, why?

Comment: not sure if the controller scope is the same as the link scope.  You might want to confirm that first.